# How use htacces to run index.php in subfolder in nginx?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I'm new in *nginx*.

I stack on run my website using *nginx*.

I have try to convert `htaccess` to use `nginx.conf` or `default.d/*.conf` but my site still is not working.

Here are my files:

```
--- .htaccess ---
 |-- public     |
 |     ---  index.php
 |     --- .htaccess
 |-- application
```

**first htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

**second htaccess** same folder with `index.php`

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This my `nginx.conf` after edit:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        autoindex off;
        location / {
        # first htaccess configuration         
        rewrite .* /public/index.php last;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

And the `default.d/*.conf`

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;
# htaccess configuration
autoindex off;
if(!-e $request_filename){
rewrite^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;
}
```

Can anyone help me to run this in nginx?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to set `.../public` as the document root, and rewrite any URI beginning with `/public/` to `/`:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;

location / {
    try_files $uri @index;
}
location @index {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}
location /public/ {
    rewrite ^/public(.*)$ $1 last;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

However, if you prefer to use your current document root, this may suit your requirements:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
    try_files $uri /public$uri @index;
}
location @index {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /public$uri =404;
    ...
}
```